# Why am I getting error when trying to install Apache-Beam?

Tags: python, pip, apache-beam

I'm getting the following error when I ran `pip install apache-beam[gcp]`:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-install-oflkun6_/fastavro/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-install-oflkun6_/fastavro/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-record-xp507tin/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/fastavro
     cwd: /private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-install-oflkun6_/fastavro/
Complete output (164 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_schema_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_schema_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/write.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_write_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_read_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_read_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_validate_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_validation_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/six.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/_timezone.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/const.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/schema.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/read.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
copying fastavro/validation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
running build_ext
building 'fastavro._read' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c fastavro/_read.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fastavro/_read.o
fastavro/_read.c:15771:267: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__5 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(5, 0, 10, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__11, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_iter_avro_records, 628, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__5)) __PYX_ERR(0, 628, __pyx_L1_error)
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15783:266: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__6 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(5, 0, 11, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__12, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_iter_avro_blocks, 648, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__6)) __PYX_ERR(0, 648, __pyx_L1_error)
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15795:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__14 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(8, 0, 8, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__13, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_init, 675, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__14)) __PYX_ERR(0, 675, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15807:253: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__7 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 2, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__15, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_iter, 685, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__7)) __PYX_ERR(0, 685, __pyx_L1_error)
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15819:253: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__17 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__16, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_str, 690, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__17)) __PYX_ERR(0, 690, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15831:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__19 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__18, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_init, 697, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__19)) __PYX_ERR(0, 697, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15846:258: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__22 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 2, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__21, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_schema_2, 724, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__22)) __PYX_ERR(0, 724, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15858:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__24 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__23, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_iter, 732, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__24)) __PYX_ERR(0, 732, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15870:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__26 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__25, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_next, 737, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__26)) __PYX_ERR(0, 737, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15882:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__28 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__27, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_init, 744, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__28)) __PYX_ERR(0, 744, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15897:254: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
  __pyx_codeobj__31 = (PyObject*)__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__30, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_fastavro__read_pyx, __pyx_n_s_init, 755, __pyx_empty_bytes); if (unlikely(!__pyx_codeobj__31)) __PYX_ERR(0, 755, __pyx_L1_error)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
fastavro/_read.c:15964:70: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  __pyx_type_8fastavro_5_read___pyx_scope_struct___iter_avro_records.tp_print = 0;
                                                                     ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
fastavro/_read.c:15970:70: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  __pyx_type_8fastavro_5_read___pyx_scope_struct_1__iter_avro_blocks.tp_print = 0;
                                                                     ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
fastavro/_read.c:15976:61: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  __pyx_type_8fastavro_5_read___pyx_scope_struct_2___iter__.tp_print = 0;
                                                            ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
fastavro/_read.c:20695:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, have 16
        __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fastavro/_read.c:318:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
          PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
          ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/code.h:122:12: note: 'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
3 warnings and 12 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-install-oflkun6_/fastavro/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-install-oflkun6_/fastavro/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k_/6pd4vmks6qj7sp1jl56khpmh0000gn/T/pip-record-xp507tin/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/fastavro Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed at head:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9701
https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/11506

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge apache-beam
```

However, I would still like why pip did not work